# SQL Statement Syntax - String vs. Parameter - MS Access - VBA

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, syntax

Select SQL Statement Grouping by CNTRY.  I'm trying to replace CNTRY with a variable string - *strtable*.  What I've done all morning, thus far, results in syntax errors.

```
If Left(lngstr1, 2) = 19 Then
    strtable = "DTG" '<---this would replace CNTRY
Else
    strtable = "US" '<---this would replace CNTRY
End If

strsql = "SELECT 'VCAP0112 - CNTRY' AS VCAP0112, [VCAP0112 - " & strtable & "].[RECV IND] AS OMU, [VCAP0112 - " & strtable & "].[LEGACY ACCT], " _
& "Sum([VCAP0112 - " & strtable & "].[1 to 30 Day]) AS [0 - 30], Sum([VCAP0112 - " & strtable & "].[RECV BALANCE]) AS TOTAL " _
& "FROM [VCAP0112 - " & strtable & "] INNER JOIN Urcrosswalk ON [VCAP0112 - " & strtable & "].[LEGACY ACCT] = Urcrosswalk.[Legacy GL]" _
& "Group BY 'VCAP0112 - CNTRY' , [VCAP0112 - " & strtable & "].[RECV IND], [VCAP0112 - " & strtable & "].[LEGACY ACCT] " _
& "HAVING ((([VCAP0112 - " & strtable & "].[RECV IND])='O' Or ([VCAP0112 - " & strtable & "].[RECV IND])='M' Or ([VCAP0112 - " & strtable & "].[RECV IND])='U'));"
```

[image]

As an attempt to resolve this myself, I've gotten to the following:

```
  strsql = "SELECT 'VCAP0112 - '& " & strtable & " AS VCAP0112,...
```

But, upon execution, Access asks for parameters for either 'DTG' or 'US' String.  When opening up the full Query in Design View, the String ('DTG' or 'US') is an unrecognized Variable.  how do I resolve this?

Comment: Never mind, I refused to go to lunch until I've found an answer...kept working at it.  Just found the correct syntax literally 5 mins after taking time to post this.  Sigh...

`strsql = "SELECT 'VCAP0112 - '& '" & strtable & "' AS VCAP0112`

Comment: . . You should either delete the question or post your comment as an answer and accept it.

Comment: @GordonLinoff - Will Do, thanxs.

Answer (score 2):

*Strtable* serves as a placeholder for which either the string 'US' or 'DTG' is to be assigned depending on an IF THEN statement.  As I had it originally 1., the string - *strtable* - will emerge as a variable needing a parameter in the SQL Statement.

To resolve this, single quotes encapsulating the double quotes that surround the variable will turn *strtable* into an actual placeholder for the string assigned to it 2.

```
 1.  Parameter: strsql = "SELECT 'VCAP0112 - '& " & strtable & " AS VCAP0112,

 2.  String: strsql = "SELECT 'VCAP0112 - '& '" & strtable & "' AS VCAP0112,
```

This...this is what I learned today.